# ASP.NET BoilerPlate: How do I inject object of DbContext in application service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

How do I inject object of DbContext in application service?

Need to access it to create clone of a entity record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `IDbContextProvider<TDbContext> _sampleDbContextProvider` as constructor injection, using with `_sampleDbContextProvider.GetDbContext();`

Comment: i use your answer but i got always null in _sampleDbContextProvider

Comment: @mohammadmobasher I also got null every time. Have you found any solution for the same? Oguzhan, any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

One tricky way to clone an entity is just serialize and then deserialize the object. Use [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) for serialization.
Simply this code can be used

```
MyEntity myEntity = _myEntityRepository.get(1);
string cloned = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEntity);
MyEntity clonedEntity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyEntity>(cloned);
clonedEntity.Id = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous, but here are a few things for you to consider:

**Dependency Injection**: AUTOFAC or NINJECT (for example)
This will allow you to *inject* your DbContext into any class via ctor or property to that you can use it.

**Pass it as a parameter** (how's your service generated?)

`var appService = new ApplicationService(new MyDbContext())`

Either one of those will work. If that wasn't what you meant, some more info will help :)