# ABP Can't create component as it has dependencies to be satisfied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am working off of the ABP Template Multipage web application https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates
I am trying to add a new page with a model, view, and controller to the project. I have added all of them and ran a successful migration into my database. When i click on the link to go to my newly added page i get the following error

**HandlerException: Can't create component 'InvoSuite.EntityFrameworkCore.InvoSuiteDbContext' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
'InvoSuite.EntityFrameworkCore.InvoSuiteDbContext' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[[InvoSuite.EntityFrameworkCore.InvoSuiteDbContext, InvoSuite.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.AssertNotWaitingForDependency()**

The page was working fine before I added code to the controller which I will post below

```
[AbpMvcAuthorize]
public class TimeCardController : InvoSuiteControllerBase
{
    InvoSuiteDbContext _Context;

    public TimeCardController(InvoSuiteDbContext context)
    {
        _Context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public TimeCardModel TimeCard { get; set; }
    public List<TimeCardModel> TimeCardList { get; set; }


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = (from timecardlist in _Context.TimeCardKey
                    select timecardlist).ToList();

        TimeCardList = data;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Table

```
[Table("tblTimeCard")]
public class TimeCardModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TimeCardID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    [Required, DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime EndOfWeek { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public decimal MondayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal TuesdayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal WednesdayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal ThursdayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal FridayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal SaturdayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal SundayHours { get; set; } = 0;
    public bool isDeleted { get; set; } = false;
}
```

And here is my DbContext

```
public class InvoSuiteDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, InvoSuiteDbContext>
{
    /* Define a DbSet for each entity of the application */
    public DbSet<TimeCardModel> TimeCardKey { get; set; }

    public InvoSuiteDbContext(DbContextOptions<InvoSuiteDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

}
```

Not sure if you need to see my View or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET BoilerPlate: How do I inject object of DbContext in application service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986872/asp-net-boilerplate-how-do-i-inject-object-of-dbcontext-in-application-service)

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: Why does it not answer your question?

Comment: I am not sure how it would answer my question. I do not understand the accepted answer or how the question is the same as mine.

Comment: You are trying to inject DbContext, which is what that question solves.